# Google map check if markers are shared with multiple polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map that has some markers.I have the coordinates or each marker and I have a drawing tool that allows me to draw polygons.

I'm trying to detect if the markers inside a drawn polygon are shared with one or more others polygons so here is my logic and code :

Logic : when I draw a polygon, I put it in an array called "polygons" then I remove the last drawn polygon from that array and I extract the locations of each marker inside it then for each marker extracted I check if it is inside an other polygon or not.

Here is my code:

The issue I have is that the variable shared_markers returns always true even if no markers are shared with 2 or more polygons. Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code that is causing the problem is where you're getting all the polygons except the last one:

```
function checkIfSharedMarkers(polygons, gmarkers){
    ...
    var all_drawn_polygons_except_last_one = polygons.splice(-1,1);
    ...
}
```

The [Array splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method modifies the original array. I compared the length of the array before and after that line was called and it was the same - therefore `all_drawn_polygons_except_last_one` still contains the last drawn polygon. I replaced that line with:

```
var all_drawn_polygons_except_last_one = polygons.slice(0, polygons.length-1)
```

which uses [Array slice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) instead of splice() (this ensures the original `polygons` array is preserved). This returns the chosen elements in a new array so `all_drawn_polygons_except_last_one` now has the last element removed.

Please see [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kUqLJW0tD29KG0LjlFF2?p=preview) for a demo.